# Gson format Java Object List to required JSON format

Tags: java, json, gson

I am getting a list of Object from a function:

```
    public List<User> getUserByOrgId(String name) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String queryString="select code,name from User where org=:name";
        Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        List<User> users= (List<User>) query.list();
        return users;
    }
```

This will be returned to the calling function which will store the result in an object list and then parse it into Json using Gson

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getUserByDepartmentId(@PathVariable("id") String id,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

List<User> usrs = this.userService.getUserByOrgId(id);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

if(!usrs.isEmpty()) {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String jsonUsr = gson.toJson(usrs);
      return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonUsr, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
else {
     return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"exists\":\"false\"}", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

This returns

```
[["1","Joe"],["2","Reg"],["3","Dash"],["4","Space"],["5","Athi"],["6","Sysot"]]
```

How do I change it so that I get the result in the form

```
{
"users": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Joe"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Reg"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why your `User` object is serialized as an array.

The following code provides better-looking JSON for your case:

```
List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User("1", "John"), new User("2", "Gill"));

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); // enable pretty printing

Map<String, List<User>> wrap = new HashMap<>();
wrap.put("users", users);  // wrap user list in a map

String json = gson.toJson(wrap);
System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Gill"
    }
  ]
}
```